# php send username to paypals donations page

Tags: url, paypal

I have a php site with a member system, and set up a paypal donations page. I've got the IPN just about working, it currently adds payments to a database.

What I want to do, is make it so when the user clicks the 'DONATE' button that takes them to paypal, it also sends the users `username` (from my site) over too. I want this username to make it through and come out the other side to the IPN script.

How can I do this? 
Do i add `&user=$username` to the paypal URL or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

**Record Keeping with Passthrough Variables**

Some variables are exclusively for your own use, such as order management. PayPal returns the values that you send through Instant Payment Notification exactly as you sent them. For this reason, they are called passthrough variables. Their values are not recorded or used by PayPal.

The following are passthrough variables:

1. custom
2. item_number or item_number_ x
3. invoice

https://cms.paypal.com/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics